# Executing multiple python pandas dataframe methods on one csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a bit new to programming in general. I've picked up a small project to automate some csv changes via pandas dataframe.

I've been able to figure out a few of the changes I need to make, unfortunately, when I print the current data frame, it only prints out the changes from one of the functions and not the other (and vice-versa).

My code so far:

```
import unicodecsv
import datetime as dt
from pandas import DataFrame

# using Pandas for table view to rename '\xef\xbb\xbfId' to 'Id'
df = pd.read_csv('Usage_sample.csv')
df.rename(columns = {'\xef\xbb\xbfId':'ID'})

# add column between ID and Client Name called "Usage Week Of"
df.insert(1,"Usage Week Of", dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
df
```

As you can see the two methods that I'm using is "rename" and "insert". Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rename` does not have effect on `df` because it returns a new dataframe which is not used. If you want to modify `df`, use `inplace`:

```
df.rename(columns = {'\xef\xbb\xbfId':'ID'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Happy001. It worked! I'll read more about inplace, since i'm anticipating adding more methods to my script.